# React Redux table update row

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm new to react and redux. 
I have a container which initialize a table component with a list of items, and onclick function. 
In the table component I have checkbox for each row. When I click the checkbox I want to select the row (change its style and add selected property to its element model). 
When I click on the checkbox I call the onclick property function, then find the item on the list by its id, and change its selected property. The view is not refreshing. 
I understand that a component is a "stupid" component that only binds the props and rendering.

What am I doing wrong?

```
// People container
<Table items={this.props.people} columns={this._columns} onRowSelect={this.selectRow} />

this.selectRow(id){
    const selectedLead =_.find(this.props.leads.docs, (lead)=>{
        return lead._id == id;
    })

    selectedLead.selected = !selectedLead.selected;
}

// Table Component - inside render()
{this.props.items.map((item, idx) => {
    console.log(item.selected);
    return <div style={styles.row(item.selected)}>etc...</div>
})}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Please provide some code of what you've tried :).

Comment: I just edited :)

Comment: How React will know that you've changed `selected` property ? If it doesn't know it will not rerender your components. You have two options here: 1) Store your `people` array inside the `this.state` of `People` component and change `selected` property using `this.setState()` method. 2) If you are using redux, store your `people` array inside redux store and change `selected` property via redux action.

Answer (score 3):

A React Component has `props` and `state`.

The difference is, that the Component will never change it `props`. But it can change it's `state`. This is why a Component will provide you the `setState(...)` Method, but no `setProps(...)` Method.

With that said, your approach to change the selected field in `this.props` is fundamentally not correct. (There also seems to be another problem in your code where you change the `selected` field in `this.props.leads`, but provide `this.props.people` to the table instead of `this.props.leads`)

Let me give you a basic example as to how I would solve your problem in Pure React (without a state library like Redux):

```
const Row = ({ item, onClick }) => (
    <tr style={styles.row(item.selected)} onClick={() => onClick(item.id)}>...</tr>
)

const Table = ({ items, onRowClick }) => (
    <table>
        {items.map(item => <Row item={item} onClick={onRowClick} />)}
    </table>
)

class PeopleTable extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = { people: props.people }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.people !== this.state.people) {
            this.setState({ people: nextProps.people })
        }
    }

    setItemSelectedState(id) {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            const people = prevState.people.map(item => ({
                ...item,
                selected: item.id === id ? !item.selected : item.selected,
            })

            return { people }
        })
    }

    handleRowClick = (id) => this.setItemSelectedState(id)

    render() {
        return (<Table items={people} onRowClick={this.handleRowClick} />)
    }
}
```

The things to notice here are:

1. `Row` and `Table` are *stateless* components. They only take `props` and return jsx. Sometimes they are also referred to as *presentational* components.
2. `PeopleTable` keeps track of the `selected` state of each item. This is why it needs `state` and must be a `class`.
3. Because we can't change a components `props`, we have to keep a reference to `props.people` in `this.state`.
4. `componentWillReceiveProps` makes sure that if our components receives another list of people, the state is updated accordingly.
5. `setItemSelectedState` goes to the root of your problem. Instead of search and update of the item (like in your `this.selectRow(id)` method), we create a complete new list of people with `map` and call `setState`. `setState` will trigger a rerender of the component and because we created a new people list, we can use the `!==` check in `componentWillReceiveProps` to check if people has changed.

I hope this answer was helpful to your question.